# GLSL Uniform evaluation

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

If in a vertex shader there is:

```
#version 450 core
uniform bool v1;

void main()
{
    if(v1 == true)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Since Uniform variables are constant throughout the shader run, how many times will the if be evaluated per frame? One? Or one per vertex (since we are in the vs)?

Comment: I believe it will execute once per vertex. Since this cannot be resolved at compile time, I believe there is noway for it to be optimized, so it must be evaluated at runtime requiring once per vertex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either it will be evaluated once per vertex, or the system will *recompile* the shader every time you change that uniform (or maybe just have 2 forms of the shader). You should prefer the former to the latter.